# Getting permissions problems when trying to SSH bitnami wordpress install

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, bitnami

Was trying to SSH to change permissions of a wordpress folder but wasn't able to...

```
bitnami@THE_IP_HERE: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Trying to see if it's the permissions on the key which I may need to change so I tried this command...

```
$ sudo chmod 600 /path/to/my/key.pem
```

and

```
$ sudo chmod 755 ~/.ssh
```

but the password found in EC2 System log doesn't seem to be correct. Am I missing something? Looking at the wrong place for the password? I am using the password given in this documentation: [https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/] or maybe I am using an old key?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. You will need to ensure you launched the instance with a valid key. If you didn't select any or selected an incorrect one, you will need to create a snapshot of the instance and launch that snapshot selecting a valid key (More info [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/#was-the-instance-created-with-an-ssh-key-pair)). If you accessed to the instance in the past but can't do it anymore, maybe you changed the permissions of the ssh folder in the remote machine and that breaks the connection. You can follow the same process I mentioned before.

Comment: That helped but I am still getting errors when trying to upload. Could I be getting this error if I don't have enough storage with the instance?:  Broken pipe (Write failed). The connection attempt was rejected. The server may be down, or your network may not be properly configured. Also I am not able to upload the folders I am trying to upload.

Comment: You can get errors related to the storage if you already accessed the instance and tried to upload a file. Those errors can be also related to the permissions of the remote folder. Can you try accessing the instance's console (using Putty or a terminal) and run the following command to know if you have enough disk space? `df -H`. You can also try copying the files in the home folder of the bitnami user or in the /tmp folder to verify if it's a permissions problem or not.